# g++ compiling with -L arg not finds a shared library

Tags: c++, g++, ld

When I execute this command

```
g++ -L/home/andrea/Desktop/cppTest/Test1/myLib -I/home/andrea/Desktop/cppTest/Test1/commons -lNames compiledObjects/SayHello.o -o SayHello
```

The compiler return this error:

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lNames
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why the compiler search "Names" here

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld
```

instead of

```
/home/andrea/Desktop/cppTest/Test1/myLib
```

That is the path specified using -L argmunt?

## Problem found

The real problem was that I've forgotten to name the library in this way libName.so

Comment: Try to move -lNames to the last position in the command. And `/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld` is just a linker command which complains about not finding library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right syntax is as follows

```
g++ -I/home/andrea/Desktop/cppTest/Test1/commons  compiledObjects/SayHello.o -o SayHello -L/home/andrea/Desktop/cppTest/Test1/myLib -lNames
```

(i.e. `-L` and `-l` options at the end).

And ensure that the directory `/home/andrea/Desktop/cppTest/Test1/` contains the library `libNames.so`.

Comment: That is a stylistic choice. That does not alter the result.

Comment: It is *not*. gcc wants the linker options at the end of the command. Just play a bit with `CFLAGS`, `LDFLAGS` and `LDLIBS` to discover. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc

Comment: I've tried but the problem is not the syntaxt but the library name